# Error: "Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of parse function." when doing try_parse() in SQL

Tags: sql, parsing, floating

What is wrong with this sql statement:

```
select TRY_PARSE( 
        ([RegionA] + 
         [RegionB] +
         [RegionC] +
         [RegionZ] +
         [Top1] +
         [Top2]) as float using 'nl-BE') Total
FROM   [dbo].[Regions]
```

I keep getting the error:

> Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of parse function.

The columns have `float` data type with `'en-US'` culture. I want the result to be in `'nl-BE'` culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRY_PARSE` works on text data; it looks like all of your columns are numeric, so it is performing addition, not string concatenation. If they are numeric: you do not need to parse. If they are intended to be text, you may need to convert them individually - but again, I suspect parsing is wrong in this case.

Comment: Thank you I applied TRY_CONVERT.